# How can I set wpf window size over screen size?Is this possible?

Tags: wpf, windows

For example screen is 1920*1080 ,but I want to set 2580*1600 for my wpf window size,Is this possible?how can I realize it?

Thank you !

Comment: you can't resize your screen over supported resolution

Comment: why'd you do that? maybe there's another alternative

Comment: describe why you want this ?.. if you set window size greater that supported the resolution then you cant resize using mouse drag but you can do it by manually like create a combo box in the centre of the  window and set or resize ...

Comment: I want a distributed rendering resolution.Every machine render part of the app, but only show a part of wpf window.